# iFrame empty in CJuidialog in YII

Tags: yii

Im using iframe inside CJuiDialog, iframe contains renderPartial to render some fields.In button click im opening dialog but dialog is empty!!! not showing fields rendered through renderPartial

My View Code:

```
<?php
$this->beginWidget('zii.Widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
'id'=>'RefList-New',
'options'=>array(
    'title'=>'Ref List Value',
    'autoOpen'=>false,
    'modal'=>true,
    'width'=>550,
    'height'=>350,
'close'=>'js:function(){                             
        }',
),
));
?>
<iframe id="cru-frame-RefNew" width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" > 
<?php  $this->renderPartial('reflist_New', array('model'=>$model,'base'=>$base)); ?>

</iframe>

<?php $this->endWidget();?>

 <?php echo CHtml::imageButton(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/new.jpg',array('id'=>'reflist-button','style'=>'display:inline-block'));?>
```

Yii script part:

```
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('uploaddfsfd', "
$('#reflist-button').click(function() { 
$('#RefList-New').dialog('open'); return false;

});
");
?>
```

when i open Dialog it is empty!!! why renderPartial part not executed? How to populate Dialog ??

Comment: where are the model and the base defined which you are passing while rendering the reflist_New?

Comment: im passing both model and the base from another view file like this   'reflists_tab'=>array(
            'title'=>'RefLists',
            'view'=>'RefList',
            'data'=>array('model'=>RefListModel::model(),'base'=>$base),
        ),

Comment: try sending the model object not like **RefListModel::model()** but like **$model=new RefList;** and then send it

Comment: Not working, Dialog is still empty only!!!

Comment: did you try it without the iframe tag?

Comment: remove the iframe tag and try. it should work.

Comment: without iframe its working but i need iframe, bcoz i nedd too render another page in the same popup so only i used iframe in popup

Comment: i set like this in javascript: $("#cru-frame-RefNew").attr("src","'.$this->renderPartial('reflist_New', array('model'=>$model,'base'=>$base)).'")  but the popup displaying before clicking button itself

Comment: is it working with render?

Comment: yes its working fine with  render!!!

Comment: Try like $this->renderPartial('reflist_New', array('model'=>$model,'base'=>$base),false,true);

Comment: The iframe is another page, which must have src attribute. Please, learn about iframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
 <iframe id="cru-frame-RefNew"src=""width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0" scrolling="yes" ></iframe>
```

In your script

```
 <?php
 Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('uploaddfsfd', "
 $('#reflist-button').click(function() {
 $('#RefList-New').dialog('open');
 $('#cru-frame-RefNew').attr('src','".CController::createUrl('yourAction',array('id'=>$model->id))."');
 return false;
 });
 ");
?>
```

In yor action

```
public function actionYourAction()
{


//renderPartial here
}
```

If you want to add one more iframe to the same dialogue box, add like,

```
$('#cru-frame-RefNew').attr('src','".CController::createUrl('yourAction',array('id'=>$model->id))."');
 return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1st, make iframe with `src`

```
<iframe id="cru-frame-RefNew" 
        width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" 
        src="<?php echo $this->createUrl('reflist') ?>" >
```

2nd, add action to controller

```
function actionReflist() {
    // fill $model and $base
    // add special layout for display it in popups dialogs
    $this->layout = "layouts/special_layouts_for_popup_dialogs.php";
    $this->render('reflist_New', array('model'=>$model,'base'=>$base));
}
```